# Rails 5 not saving dates correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I'm having a weird issue where Rails is not saving a date correctly.  I've tried formatting the date a number of ways, including as an actual date object as well as various string formats, but it's wanting to swap the month and day regardless.  When this results in an invalid date (ie 28/08/2019 as mm/dd/yyyy), it fails to include the parameter all together when saving.

If the date is valid when swapped (ie 2019-09-03 ==> 2019-03-09), it will save the incorrect (swapped) date.

```
params[:shift_date] = Date.strptime(shift_params[:shift_date], '%m/%d/%Y').to_date
@shift.save(params)
```

Results in...

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"shift_date"=>Tue, 03 Sep 2019, "start_time"=>"00:00:00", "end_time"=>"00:00:00"} permitted: true>
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
↳ app/controllers/api/shifts_controller.rb:25
Shift Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "shifts" ("shift_date", "start_time", "end_time") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["shift_date", "2019-03-09"], ["start_time", "00:00:00"], ["end_time", "00:00:00"]]
```

With a date like '08/29/2019', again correctly interpreted into a Date object, when saved it will be omitted since 2019-29-08 is not a valid date.  I've also tried converting to a string `2019-08-29`, `2019-08-29 00:00:00`, etc etc, and it always get its wrong no matter what I do.  I'm very surprised passing a correctly set and valid `Date` object that Rails would change it at all...

Note this only happens in the controller.  Via the console everything works as expected...

```
2.6.3 :076 > s.shift_date = Date.strptime('08/28/2019', '%m/%d/%Y')
 => Wed, 28 Aug 2019 
2.6.3 :077 > s.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Shift Update (0.4ms)  UPDATE "shifts" SET "shift_date" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "shifts"."id" = $3  [["shift_date", "2019-08-28"], ["updated_at", "2019-08-28 20:48:31.944877"], ["id", 54]]
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
 => true
```

Comment: I see it's an API call so please consider using `ISO 8601` format.

Comment: I have tried formatting it in `ISO 8601` format but Rails still swaps the month and day regardless